# CSV Data Pulled in as PHP Form Options

Tags: php, forms, csv, import

I have a CSV file (say "../datarange.csv", made up of 8 columns and a variable amount of rows deep:

```
HEADER1,HEADER2,HEADER3...HEADER8
DATA001,DATA122,DATA355...DATA888
DATA002,DATA102,DATA322...DATA876
DATA003,DATA176,DATA344...DATA811
                DATA435...DATA222
                DATA311
```

I want to pull in only the data under "HEADER8" and have it populate a drop-down "option select" menu in a form using PHP. Each individual like down under "HEADER8" will be its own individual option.

The idea is that users, on another form, submit data to populate "HEADER8" with suggested names, like brainstorming for a new feature's name. THIS form is to allow users to vote on the final selection and the form will write to a new CSV (this works fine though - I just need to pull in the CSV data from the previous CSV and make it the option menu in this form).

I don't need to pull it from a database or even touch MySql - only part of this I'm having trouble with is pulling from the old CSV to create the drop-down selection menu.

I appreciate the help!

Comment: Above CSV doesn't look like a valid CSV! missing fields should be `,,`

Comment: The above CSV is just an example to show that I do, indeed, have variable lengths and need the script to automatically know when there's no more data under "Header8", and to stop displaying drop-down options at that point.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

[fgetcsv](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.fgetcsv.php)    should help you here.

```
$header8 = array();
if (($handle = fopen("../datarange.csv", "r")) !== FALSE) {
    while (($data = fgetcsv($handle)) !== FALSE) {
        //input logic to skip first row
        $header8[$data[7]] = $data[7];
    }
}
```